# Does it sound idiomatic to use two consecutive "devoir"s?

Tags: conditionnel

> Si notre compagnie **était** reprise par X, elle en **supporterait** les conséquences !
>
> {vs}: Si notre compagnie **devait** être reprise par X, elle **devrait** en supporter les conséquences !

The use of "devoir" serves to indicate that their occurrence is somewhat less probable than what would be the case with the version described without it.

But does it sound idiomatic to use two consecutive "devoir"s like this, both in the subordinate and the main clause? Or should I limit its use to either of the two clauses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je ne suis pas d'accord avec les autres réponses, parce que je pense que la répétition de "devoir" est ambiguë, et devrait donc être évitée.

Soit vous voulez dire :

> Il y a une probabilité que notre entreprise soit reprise, et alors elle en supportera inévitablement les conséquences.

Soit :

> Si notre entreprise venait à être reprise, il faudrait (moralement, ou dans notre intérêt) que ce soit elle (et personne d'autre) qui en supporte les conséquences.

Plus simplement, la première phrase se reformulerait :

> Si notre entreprise devait être reprise, elle en supporterait les conséquence.

Et la seconde :

> Si notre entreprise venait à être reprise, elle devrait en supporter les conséquences.

Comment: « Elle » représente une employée ou une personne ayant un lien avec l'entreprise, pas l'entreprise elle-même (voir les commentaires d'Alone-zee après ma réponse).

Comment: Ca ne change pas ma réponse mais je suis d'accord que nous disons la même chose.

Comment: Hi. Regarding "Si notre entreprise venait à être reprise, elle ***devrait*** en supporter les conséquences": Is it impossible to interpret this "devrait" as "elle ***pourrait / might*** en supporter les conséquences"?

Comment: Ce n'est pas la répétition de `devoir` qui est ambiguë, uniquement sa deuxième utilisation.

Comment: @Alone-zee It is possible to interpret it this way indeed.

Comment: @Alone-zee : si vous voulez absolument éviter cette interprétation, vous pouvez dire "il faudra que", "il faudrait que", "j'espère que" selon votre degré d'espoir.

Answer (score 0):

French tend to avoid repeating the same word or verb, unless it is done for stylish effects so I would suggest:

> Si notre société<sup>1</sup> était reprise par X, elle devrait en supporter les conséquences !

Note that the sentence is ambiguous. It is unclear what *elle* refers to, the acquiring company, the one being absorbed, or (actually the case) something else.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Company is better translated by *société*, *entreprise*, or just *boite* in casual speech.</sub>

Comment: Hi. I intended "elle" to mean "she {person}", not the company. How would you paraphrase the sentence, then?

Comment: Ah, okay. It was impossible to guess without context. If you are talking about that person before, you can keep *elle* and that would stay clear. Otherwise, replace *elle* by that person's first or last name (e.g. *Marie*, or *Mme Martin*), or her title/function (e.g. *la commerciale*).

Answer (score 0):

As @jlliagre said, `French tend to avoid repeating the same word or verb` but in that case, I believe that it depends on what exactly you want to say.

> Si notre société **(était/devait être)** reprise par X, elle *devrait* en supporter les conséquences !

This sentence has two meanings to me, the important part being the second `devoir` :

1. The company<sup>1</sup> ***should*** and ***will*** take consequences
2. The company<sup>1</sup> ***is probably*** prepared to take consequences (and probably isn't)

For the first `devoir` in the sentence, it only depends on how much you want to express the possibility for this case to happen. If you believe you should use it, then use it.

For the second `devoir`, I believe it is ambiguous because of the tense you use.
It's more common to use future tense if what you are saying is that the company **will** take consequences.

> Si notre société devait être reprise par X, elle **devra** en supporter les conséquences !
>
> Si notre société devait être reprise par X, elle en **supportera** les conséquences !

If it's not what you were trying to say, then keep using *conditionnel* tense and for the repeating of the verb `devoir`, if I had to remove one, it will be the first occurence, but it's not an obligation.

<sub><sup>1</sup>or to whatever refers *elle* in your sentence</sub>